# Should certificates be always imported in keystores?

Tags: java, cryptography, certificate

I'm doing some crytography in Java and I wanted to know what are the best and common pratices on certificate storage.

Can certificates be loaded from a file or should they always be imported in keystore/truststore ?

---

**EDIT:** My use case is to load a private key and a certificate in order to be able to crypt and decrypt data.

The question is: should the private key and the certificate be both in a keystore or can the certificate be aside in a file ?

Comment: For more security, yes.

Comment: It would be better to describe what you are trying to pull off, and as Suresh said, yes.

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer. Do you have some articles or resources discussing the potential issues ?

Comment: Too broad, and your last request is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend storing the certificates at least in the key store. If your key store and file have about the same access rights security is not that much different - although the password does add a level of protection (it's not called "changeit" by default for nothing).

Java and Java key stores are however pretty focused on X.509 based PKI, and you may not be even store the private key successfully without the certificate. So it is certainly best practice to store the certificate or rather, the certificate chain in the key store.